# enable submit button only when all the condition of textboxes are satisfied

Tags: jquery, html

I want that my submit button should be enabled only when both the conditions are satisfied,. 
right now it is more like when i enter the value in first field it enables once then when i go to next field it again get disabled then get enabled .. i want unleass and untill both the input field condition is not met it should not get enabled.

```js
$('#accinput').on('keyup paste',username_check);
$('#Cusinput').on('keyup paste',username_check1);

function username_check(){ 

  var username = $('#accinput').val();
    setTimeout( function() {
 username = $('#accinput').val();
 if(username === "" || username.length < 4){
  $("#btnsubmit").prop('disabled', true);
}
else{
    $("#btnsubmit").prop('disabled', false);
}
    },100);

}

function username_check1(){ 
  var username = $('#Cusinput').val();
    setTimeout( function() {
 username = $('#Cusinput').val();
 if(username === "" || username.length < 3){
$("#btnsubmit").prop('disabled', true);
}
else{
    $("#btnsubmit").prop('disabled', false);
}
    },100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input type="text" class="btn btn-info"  id="accinput" required/>

  <input type="text" class="btn btn-info"  id="Cusinput" required>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button" id="btnsubmit"  >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small code to help you. You need to have an `input` event on the textfields that would call the function and do the necessary condition checks. This code would work if you have dynamic elements or few more elements than the sample code provided in the question. You just have to ensure that they should have the class name `form-field`:

```js
$('.form-field').on('input', checkAndEnableButton);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnsubmit").prop('disabled', true);
});

function checkAndEnableButton() {
  $("#btnsubmit").prop('disabled', true);
  var breakFlag = false;
  var enteredVal = '';
  $('.form-field').each(function() {
    enteredVal = $(this).val();
    if (enteredVal == '' || enteredVal.length < 4)
      breakFlag = true;
  });

  if (!breakFlag) {
    $("#btnsubmit").prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="btn btn-info form-field" id="accinput" required/>

<input type="text" class="btn btn-info form-field" id="Cusinput" required>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button" id="btnsubmit">
```

Comment: what if both the input fields have two different conditions ?

Comment: Well, in that case we need to tweak the code a little. As of its a concise code, assuming all input fields will have same conditions. You can write  field specific conditions in the `checkAndEnableButton` function.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked fine for different condition and dynamic conditions too ... Thankyou :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote and mark this as close. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```js
function validate () {
  var inputs = $('input[type="text"]');
  if ($.grep(inputs, i => $(i).val().length > 3).length === inputs.length) {
    $("#btnsubmit").removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#btnsubmit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('input', validate);
$('#add-input').on('click', function () {
  var newInput = $('<input type="text" required">');
  newInput.on('input', validate);
  $("#btnsubmit").before(newInput);
  validate();
});
validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Button" id="btnsubmit">
</div>
<button id="add-input">Add input field</button>
```

Now, it works with any number of `input[type="text"]` elements. Of course, you can change that selector. For example, give all input elements that you care about a `min-length` class and then select `.min-length`.

Comment: This worked but what if these fields are going to be added dynamically based on some selection values and their is possibility that only one can exist or both can exist ?